# Kentico: How do I parse the contents of a Widget when using the TreeProvider.SelectNodes object to retrieve content

Tags: c#, .net, api, kentico

I am building an index for an external search engine and I am having issues parsing /rendering the content of inline widgets in the WYSIWYG.

```
DocumentQuery articleDetailNodes = tree.SelectNodes("ArticleViewModel");

foreach (TreeNode general in articleDetailNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Adding [Article]: " + general.GetValue("DocumentName").ToString());
    generalIndex.Add(new GeneralIndexItem
    {
        objectID = general.NodeGUID.ToString(),
        title = general.GetValue("DocumentName")?.ToString(),
        description = CMS.MacroEngine.MacroResolver.Resolve(general.GetValue("Body").ToString()),
        excerpt = general.Parent.GetValue("Excerpt")?.ToString() + " " + general.Parent.GetValue("CardTitle")?.ToString() + " " + general.Parent.GetValue("CardSubtitle")?.ToString() + " " + general.Parent.GetValue("CardDescription")?.ToString(),
        page_url = domain + general.NodeAliasPath
    });
}
```

I am expecting the value of description to be rendered HTML, but instead I am getting:

```
{^widget|(widget_displayname)Color+Family+Filter+-+Large|(name)ColorFamilyFilter_Large|(width)|(height)^}<br />\r\n&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to index widgets, you should consider to use Smart search crawler instead of making custom index. If you need to customize it, you can check on this [link](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/customizing-the-content-of-search-indexes) or with this peace of code:

```
if (e.IsCrawler)
{
     TreeNode page = e.Node;

     e.SearchDocument.Add("path_field_name", page.NodeAliasPath, true, true);
}
```

Comment: The requirement is basically output the content of each page as JSON (Conversion happens later in my code). Smart search is not an option.

Comment: You can query search from your code instead of using document queries to query database. Instead of tree.SelectNodes("ArticleViewModel"), you can call search to get page that you need and for search text use: classname: pageTypeCodename.